# Spell resistance and holding the charge

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, spell-resistance

If you are holding a charge and you attack a creature with SR and hit it, but fail to overcome the SR check, does the spell dissipate or do you continue to hold the charge and just not affect the creature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The spell is discharged whether the target resists it or not

Spell resistance doesn't prevent spells being cast or discharged, it only allows a creature the chance to resist the effect:

> If the caster fails the check, the spell doesn’t affect the creature.

The spell doesn't *affect* the creature, but the spell was still cast, or discharged. The caster doesn't get to keep the resources it cost them to cast that spell - it had to happen in the first place for the target to get the chance to resist it.

The *spell resistance* special ability also doesn't describe any special interaction with the rules for holding a charge, which state that:

> If you touch anything or anyone while holding a charge, even unintentionally, the spell discharges.

There are no caveats to this; it doesn't matter if you touch something or someone that resists or is immune to the spell's effect, whether by spell resistance or some other mechanic. The spell is unfortunately discharged whether it's useful or not.

Comment: I’d really like to see basis for this answer that *doesn’t* rely on that line, if possible—the unintentional discharge rule is full of potential for awful unintentional consequences, and should generally be ignored. It seems like it should be possible to back this answer up without using it, too, though I’d have to check.

Comment: Ive always taken that line a bit loosely as a gm rather than a strict interpretation. Always looked at it as, "There is precedent for this to happen, but if you follow this too closely you break action economy, so dont." Similar to how command words can be used "Accidentally"